# Why is inner product denoted like this?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Why the inner product is denoted in every book like this: $\langle,\rangle$ instead of some name like $IP\colon V \times V \rightarrow F$? And what does the notation $\langle|\rangle$ and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ have to do with this? Can someone explain?

Comment: I don't know the historical reason for the notation, but there are many instances of binary functions where an infix notation is more convenient than a prefix notation. Even simpler examples include addition of real numbers, which is really a function $\mathrm{add} : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, but writing $x+y$ instead of $\mathrm{add}(x,y)$ (or even $a(x,y)$ or whatever) clarifies matters considerably e.g. the associativity axiom: $x+(y+z)=(x+y)+z$ versus $a(x,a(y,z))=a(a(x,y),z)$.

Comment: I don't know the answer either, but I like that^ response.

Comment: Also, well. (1) Inner product is *sometimes* written in the usual functional way, when it's to emphasize it is indeed a function (e.g. in [communication complexity](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~rdewolf/cc.pdf)); (2) Is your middle question referring to the "bra-ket" notation of inner product in quantum physics?

Comment: I suggest the tags [tag:math-notation] and [tag:math-history] if that is what you are interested in

Comment: @ClementC. Yes, I am too referring to the bra-ket notation but I have no idea how it is used here and if there is any difference. Disclaimer: I am not familiar with quantum mechanics and bra-ket notation.

Comment: There is none, except that it's an inner product in a complex vector space (Hilbert space). The whole notation is a pun: you write your vectors as $|x\rangle$, their transpose as $\langle x|$, so the inner product $\langle\langle x|,|y\rangle\rangle$ can be written more shortly as $\langle x|y\rangle$.

Comment: Why its transpose? What does it have to do with this? Shouldn't it be an arbitrary vector?

Comment: I should have said conjugate, the analogue of transposition in complex spaces. The inner product can be computed as $x^Ty $ where $x^T$ is the transpose of $x$.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose

Answer (score 1):

It's just historical notational conventions from mathematics and physics, much like any piece of notation in mathematics.

Things like $\langle|\rangle$ or $\langle,\rangle$ or $\langle\cdot|\cdot\rangle$ or $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ are used to be able to denote/view/think of the inner product as a map on the product space $V\times V$.  So you might write things like:

\begin{align}
\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle:V\times V&\rightarrow F\\
(v,v')&\mapsto \langle v,v'\rangle.
\end{align}

To create even more confusion, sometimes "round brackets" $(\cdot,\cdot)$ are also used to denote inner products..

Comment: Can I think of the dots as imaginable $x$ and $y$ like this: $f(x,y)$? Also what is the relation between this, bra-ket notation and between the inner product and the dual space?

Comment: Yes the dots just indicate where the arguments of the inner product go in the notation, so it is kind of like writing $f(\cdot,\cdot)$ for a function of two variables.

Comment: A finite-dimensional vector space $V$ is linearly isomorphic to its dual space, so every linear functional $f:V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by $v\mapsto f(v)$ on $V$ can be identified with a unique element $v^*$ of $V$ via the inner product, in which case we have $f(v)=\langle v^*,v\rangle=\langle v^*|v\rangle$.  The bra-ket notation makes this identification easy to write down:  we simply write $f=\langle v^*|$ and thus think of $\langle v^*|$ as the linear functional.

Comment: It's also common to think of $v^*$ itself as the linear functional and write $v^*(v)$ for $\langle v^*,v\rangle$ or $\langle v^*|v\rangle$, etc, whatever notation you're using.

Comment: How can $v^*$ be a linear functional and an element of $V$ (first sentence, second comment)?

Comment: $v^*$ is _viewed_ or _thought of_ as a linear functional since the map $v\mapsto\langle v^*,v\rangle$ is the actual linear functional, and every linear functional on $V$ can be uniquely identified with an element of $V$ in this way.

Comment: So, this is what I understand: We have a dual space which is $V^*$ and that consists of linear functionals. Now we want to every functional $f:V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ to associate a member of $V$ called $v^*$. How we do this? May you please elaborate from here describing the notation you use along the way? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I just did above (the association is made via the inner product), and it is also explained in most linear algebra books:  You prove that the inner product space $V$ and its dual $V^*$ have the same dimension and the map $V\mapsto V^*$ given by $v^*\mapsto \langle v^*,\cdot\rangle=\langle v^*|$ is a linear space isomorphism.  Also consider the Riesz representation theorem, which is the analogous statement for infinite dimensional (Hilbert) spaces.